# The wackiest bug I've ever seen

Tags: c#, debugging

I have a situation I can't explain. Look at the following code and notice how the variables `c` and `d` are defined and their values are strange. `c` equals `null` but `d` doesn't. Surely this is impossible(right?) given the following things I'm 100% certain of:

- a.value is a field, not a property
- the type qualifier is a sealed reference type, with base type object
- The application is just single threaded.
- I've done 'Clean Solution'.

Now the weirdest thing is that when I stop the debug run, replace the variable reference `c` in the lambda expression in the bottom line by `d` and build and run again, `d` is `null but`c` isn't!

```
private static object CreateConstraints(CompositeElement constraintsElement)
{
    Contract.Requires(constraintsElement != null);

    var constraintTypes = from e in constraintsElement where e.DefinitionName.IsAnyOf("ConstraintType", "ConstraintTypeNamePrependedWithComma") select (Qualifier)e.Value;
    var declarer = (MemberDeclaration)constraintsElement.Parent.Value;
    GenericTypeParameterCollection genericTypeParameters = declarer.Name.Suffixes.OfType<GenericTypeParameterCollection>().First();

    Element a = constraintsElement["TypeName"];
    a.SetValue();
    var c = a.value as Qualifier;
    var d = a.value as Qualifier;

    genericTypeParameters.First(gp => gp.Type == c).Constraints.AddRange(constraintTypes);

    return null;
}
```

I've also made [screenshots of the disassemblies](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/853/assemblycandd.png/)
 of both runs. Personally I don't know for sure whether they're incorrect.

So I want to ask if I'm missing something which could make this perfectly normal behavior, or is there something really weird going on here?

Comment: I realize the code isn't readable. How can I make the image clickable so it appears larger?

Comment: Rather than do that, post the code itself as text - ideally in a short but complete program that demonstrates the problem. Have you managed to reproduce the problem *not* in the debugger?

Comment: Why don't you just paste your code?

Comment: I've tried that, but I can't reproduce it in a small application. I've been trying that for the past hour or so, unsuccessfully

Comment: Ok pasted the code. Now you have to trust me when I say c is null and d doesn't. In the image you could see that in the locals window....

Comment: Could be an access to modified closure...

Comment: Why does the locals window show `c` twice with two different values, and does it show `d` twice with two different values if you change the lambda expression to use `d` instead of `c`? Why is there a squiggle under the `==` in the lambda expression (what does the IDE say for that squiggle)? Are there also fields named `c` and `d`? What happens if you output `Object.ReferenceEquals(c, d)`?

Comment: This is the deleted image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/mr0QT.png

Comment: @Jason, I hadn't even seen the second `c`! And yes there is a second `d` in the case I replace `c` with `d` in the lambda expressions. The squiggle is Resharper telling me there's a reference comparison where I might have meant value comparison.

Comment: @Jason, replacing `gp.Type == c` with either `ReferenceEquals(gp.Type, c)` or `ReferenceEquals(gp.Type, d)` doesn't really change anything in the locals window....

Comment: @JBSnorro: Well, the locals window seems to think that there are two variables named `c` (or `d`, depending on which you have in the lambda expression). Do the following. Delete the `c` from `var c = a.value as Qualifier;`. Name it `foo`. Now copy and paste `foo` into the lambda expression. Rinse, repeat with `d`. What happens?

Comment: @Jason, two `foo`s is what happens. Both when replacing either `c` or `d`

Comment: Looks like a code generation bug to me.  The a.value field has different addresses in the screenshot.  The code is too convoluted to create a repro.  There's a known bug with using as or is with nullable types, this doesn't look like a match.  Use connect.microsoft.com to report the bug.

Comment: @JBSnorro: Then this has to be a bug. Post on Microsoft Connect.

Comment: @Jason, Hans. Ok, I'll do so in an hour or so and post the link here. Thnx for the swift responses and help!

Answer (score 2):

Call me daft but I don't really see a problem.

- from the description, there is no 'bug' . (Or does your programs logic go astray?)
- all we have is a variable `c` appearing twice in a Debugger window.
- one instance of `c` has the right type (and I assume the right value).
- the other one is null. This must be a view of the *captured* `c` and since the lambda is not executing it is `null`.

So what is supposed to be the problem?

You could try putting a breakpoint inside the lambda.

Comment: The problem is that I didn't see the second `c`, so that would mean assigning the same instance(`a.value`) to two different local variables yielded different results... But indeed, the only real problem is a variable appearing twice in the locals window. That did direct me in the totally wrong direction while debugging though, because I concluded something impossible had happened(`c != d`). And however you look at it, that still is a bug

Comment: A simple `Debug.Assert(c == d);` could cleared things up a lot.

Comment: Yes, but why would I even think of such an assertion when I've already conluded `c!=d` from the locals window. I didn't even consider `c==d` until I knew of the second `c`

Comment: When you see conflicting/confusing info, look for a 2nd source and try to verify.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your debugger screenshot from before the edit, I notice that the local "c" is listed twice, once with value null, once with a value as an instance of a qualifier. This seems weird, and makes me suspect a bug in C#'s compilation of the lambda expression. As a workaround, try using an explicit delegate instead.

Also, there is an error squiggle on the double equals in the lambda expression. Hovering over that to get the error message may provide a clue as to what is going on.

Comment: Please allow for the asynchronous nature of posting. I did not see all the comments that came in as I was looking at your question and writing an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there is an exception being thrown deep in the call stack and the exception handling is being done in such a way as to prevent the assignments from being done properly.